# Read in int array as a vector from lines of txt file with last few column missing. data sperated by some spaces

Tags: python, pandas

input file looks like

```
   98021      98022      98023      98024      98025      98026      98027      98028      98029      98030 \n

   98031      98032      98033      98034      98035      98036      98037      98038      98039      98040 \n

   98041      98042      98043      98044      98045      98046      98047      98048      98049      98050 \n

   98051      98052      98053      98054      98055 \n
```

No header line. Numbers are separated by some spaces. I know each line has exactly 10 integers, except for the last line, which has <= 10 numbers. The file might be big say over 10M lines. So I hope to use pandas to speed things up. Tried some different read_csv() parameters, but can not make it work.

Want: vector of all the integers in the C order.
i.e. something like 98021,98022,98023,...,98054,98055

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
       for word in line.split():
           a.append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
In [11]: pd.read_fwf("data.csv")
Out[11]:
   98021  98022  98023  98024  98025    98026    98027    98028    98029    98030
0  98031  98032  98033  98034  98035  98036.0  98037.0  98038.0  98039.0  98040.0
1  98041  98042  98043  98044  98045  98046.0  98047.0  98048.0  98049.0  98050.0
2  98051  98052  98053  98054  98055      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN

In [12]: pd.read_fwf("data.csv", header=None)
Out[12]:
       0      1      2      3      4        5        6        7        8        9
0  98021  98022  98023  98024  98025  98026.0  98027.0  98028.0  98029.0  98030.0
1  98031  98032  98033  98034  98035  98036.0  98037.0  98038.0  98039.0  98040.0
2  98041  98042  98043  98044  98045  98046.0  98047.0  98048.0  98049.0  98050.0
3  98051  98052  98053  98054  98055      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

---

To get a single array:

```
In [21]: a = pd.read_fwf("data.csv", header=None).values.ravel()

In [22]: a[~np.isnan(a)]
Out[22]:
array([98021., 98022., 98023., 98024., 98025., 98026., 98027., 98028.,
       98029., 98030., 98031., 98032., 98033., 98034., 98035., 98036.,
       98037., 98038., 98039., 98040., 98041., 98042., 98043., 98044.,
       98045., 98046., 98047., 98048., 98049., 98050., 98051., 98052.,
       98053., 98054., 98055.])
```